# ElasticSearch aggregation not showing count

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got my ElasticSearch running with different document types.
One type just includes a "tag" and a "source" field, both of the type "string". No other (mapping) properties given.
Now I would like to check which of those tags are the most frequent ones within my database.

Based on several examples given here on Stack Overflow and on the official [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html), I've written this simple request (using PhpStorm HTTP-Client):

```
GET http://els.local:9200/my_index/my_doc_type/_search
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "group_by" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag",
                "order" : { "_count" : "desc" }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I tested this in tozens of different ways, like this for example:

```
    {
        "size" : 0,
        "aggs" : {
            "tags" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "tag",
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

Based on the documentation, I should at least get an approximate count of how often the tags are found (see the given link for the ELS documentation), but instead my result does look like this (shortened result for better readability):

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 62556,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_doc_type",
        "_id": "AWMmMfYVqn7lskkxZiWO",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "tag": "Some random tag",
          "source": "my source code 14124"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_doc_type",
        "_id": "AWMmMfwmqn7lskkxZiWc",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "tag": "Some other random tag",
          "source": "my source code 235"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
The ElasticSearch version seems to be "5.6.8." by the way, even though it should be the current one in the near future.

Comment: It doesn't add up, with `size: 0` you should not get any `hits` in the response. Looks like the request body is not being sent. Query looks correct.

Comment: Thank you, @NikolayVasiliev! I was so focused on the content of the query, that I never tried to completely remove it. I checked the original documentation again, and it does say "GET", but after changing it to "POST", I finally got an error to work with. I will try further and post an answer as soon as I get it to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nikolay I finally found the error.
I don't know if the PhpStorm HTTP Client has a problem, or if the ElasticSearch documentation is wrong, but when I changed the `GET` to `POST`, I finally got an error message.

```
"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [tag] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
```

After changing my field type from `string` to `keyword` within the mapping, I got the expected result :)